# Problem with Formula in Python script for LibreOffice Calc

Tags: python, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I'm starting work with LibreOffice Calc instead of Excel for my new job. I was (kind of) used to program in VBA. But, as I have to change programs, I want to change the language too. I have a Python basic notion, but I am having some difficulties.

**Objective**

I want to write a formula by a macro and see the result.

```
#!/bin/python3

#Script usado no programa Form_Atendimento.ods

#Cria objeto document, referenciando o documento aberto
document = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()

#Cria objeto sheets, referenciando as planilhas
sheets = document.getSheets()

#Função que configura os parâmetros para que seja escrita a função =HOJE
def write_today():
    
    information = '=HOJE()'
    sheet = 'Form'
    location = 'B5'
    write_function(information, sheet, location)
    
    return 0

#Função que escreve qualquer função
def write_function(information, sheet, location):

    sheetForm = sheets.getByName(sheet)
    sheetForm.getCellRangeByName(location).setString(information)
    
    
    
    return 0
```

Intended Result:
[image]

Aquaired Result:
[image]

I also tried change 'sheetForm.getCellRangeByName(location).setString(information)' for 'sheetForm.getCellRangeByName(location).setFormula(information)', but the result is bad too:
[image]

**Information:**

- =HOJE() is the same of =TODAY(), but in Portuguese.
- #NOME? is the same of #NAME?
- LibreOffice Version: 7.1.4.2 (x64) / LibreOffice Community

**Another question:**
Where can I find some (good) documentation of commands and functions to write Python scripts for LibreOffice Calc?

Best regards!

Comment: `.setString()`? Why not `.setFormula()`? And Calc will better understand what you want if you still ask for =TODAY(), and not =HOJE(). The most dangerous place in your function is [**.getByName()**](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/container/XNameAccess.html#getByName), here you can expect `NoSuchElementException`, `WrappedTargetException` and `RuntimeException`. Therefore, it is better to wrap it all in `try - except`

Comment: Hi @JohnSUN, thank you for your answer. I have tried `.setFormula()`, but didn't worked. After your comment, I used `=TODAY()` (combined with `.setFormula()`) instead of `=HOJE()` (even my LibreOffice configured in Portuguese) and it worked!

Comment: Either of you should post the answer and the OP should mark it as the right one. This way it's useful for everyone.